# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlet

Пишу приложение в IDEA с использованием сервлетов+jsp+mysql. Запускаю в Tomcat и получаю ошибку

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

type Exception report
message Servlet execution threw an exception
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ru.testScandJavaJsp.model.DatabaseList
    ru.testScandJavaJsp.controller.ReportOut.doGet(ReportOut.java:37)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.75 logs.
```

собираю с помощью мавена, вот стек:

```
C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\bin\catalina.bat run
[2017-04-11 09:17:46,884] Artifact testScandJavaJsp:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\15.Acer\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_testScandJavaJsp"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.75"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jan 18 2017 20:54:42 UTC
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.75.0
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\15.Acer\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_testScandJavaJsp
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.75
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\15.Acer\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_testScandJavaJsp\conf\logging.properties
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\endorsed
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\15.Acer\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_testScandJavaJsp
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.75
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\temp
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Acer\abFiles\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MDL Shared\ISIS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Java\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\15.Acer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.
апр 11, 2017 9:17:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
апр 11, 2017 9:17:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
апр 11, 2017 9:17:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 554 ms
апр 11, 2017 9:17:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
апр 11, 2017 9:17:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
апр 11, 2017 9:17:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
апр 11, 2017 9:17:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
апр 11, 2017 9:17:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 54 ms
Connected to server
[2017-04-11 09:17:54,831] Artifact testScandJavaJsp:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
апр 11, 2017 9:17:55 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.
[2017-04-11 09:17:55,726] Artifact testScandJavaJsp:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-04-11 09:17:55,726] Artifact testScandJavaJsp:war exploded: Deploy took 895 milliseconds
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_scand
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at ru.testScandJavaJsp.model.DatabaseList.a(DatabaseList.java:45)
    at ru.testScandJavaJsp.model.DatabaseList.<clinit>(DatabaseList.java:28)
    at ru.testScandJavaJsp.controller.ReportOut.doGet(ReportOut.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
апр 11, 2017 9:17:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\webapps\manager
апр 11, 2017 9:17:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\webapps\manager has finished in 71 ms
```

Comment: _The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.75 logs_ Вот этот full stack trace в вопрос и добавьте.

Comment: добавьте информацию о том какой у вас проект, как собираете и как разворачиваете.

Comment: добавил весь стек

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось починить самостоятельно. Нужно добавить

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ());
```

перед тем, как получить соединение